# How to remove hidden R variables from within a function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove an R variable prefixed by a `.` from within a function call. I am receiving an error that the variable cannot be found, even though it exists and I can remove it with no issues with `remove()`:

```
> .a = "a"
> .a
[1] "a"
> remove(.a)
> .a
Error: object '.a' not found
```

However, If I wrap this remove call inside a function then I get an error even though `.a` exists:

```
> .a = "a"
> .a
[1] "a"
> Clear <-function(){remove(.a)}
> Clear()
Warning message:
In remove(.a) : object '.a' not found

> .a
[1] "a"
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: `remove`/`rm` only works within the scope of the function by default. There is no object called `.a` in your function's environment, only in the global environment. Take a look at `?remove` and note that there is an `envir=` argument.

Comment: Thanks the @latemail, solved it almost straight away looking at the docs with `Clear<-function(){remove(.a, envir=.GlobalEnv)`